# How to overcome weird "placeholder" issue in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari

I'm facing a very weird bug on my website, a bug that only surfaces in mobile Safari (tested on iPhone5, iOS8.1). Below are a few links to live pages where each page has a search input control:

http://www.jungledragon.com/search
http://www.jungledragon.com/tags
http://www.jungledragon.com/wildlifemap/countries

The weird behavior is that when using mobile Safari, after typing 2 or 3 characters the background of the parent element as well as the input control itself dissapear. All that remains is the cursor itself.

Here's the markup of the input control of the first example:

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" autocomplete="off" placeholder="- search the jungle -" value="" class="searchfield" />
```

I've been stripping away attributes, changing names, etc of that input box until I figured out what triggered it. It turns out it is the placeholder attribute. When I remove it, the issue is gone.

I've been looking online for known problems with placeholder attributes in mobile Safari, but I've found nobody with this weird issue. I am there suspecting that it is using placeholder in combination with some other thing to trigger this bug.

Of course an easy solution would be to remove placeholder text altogether, but I find that solution to be too brute force for now, and I'm really curious what this bug is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say what the relation to the `placeholder` attribute might be, removing it with the Safari inspector didn't seem to have much affect on my end, but I was able to find a possible solution.

If I disable the `-webkit-transform` hack on the `header.site` element, the rendering issue no longer occurs.

#### Disabled CSS:

[image: disable transform hack]

## Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

There seems to be a number of issues with using these GPU acceleration hacks in the latest iOS versions.

#### Alternate Solution:

One good hack deserves another I suppose. It seems this rendering issue can also be countered by adding `-webkit-transform: translate(0);` to one of the elements in the `input` tree, or even the `input` element itself.

Comment: Thanks so much Alexander. I didn't use the inspector to remove the placeholder, rather I removed it from the actual code and that made the issue go away. I'm not sure why removing it with the inspector doesn't have the same effect. I fully agree that the transform hacks are buggy, especially since iOS8. Unfortunately, I don't want to remove them, because I need it for inertia scrolling, it makes quite a difference in user experience. Your answer is good though, it doesn't solve it directly, so I'll await some other answers, otherwise you'll get the "accept".

Comment: @Ferdy I came up with an alternate solution that appears to allow you to keep the hack. See my edited answer.

Comment: That actually totally makes sense! The issue consisted of the input field hiding behind a layer, by giving it its own layer, it can be solved. Will try it tonight and let you know!

Comment: Tested your alternative solution and it works flawlessly, also deployed to the live site now. Thanks, the bounty is yours!